# Disconnectedness, completeness and compactness.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

I am in search of examples of metric space which is

1) Complete but not compact

2) Not complete but disconnected

3) Connected but not Complete

4) Compact but not connected.

5) Complete but not disconnected.

I assure the users that this question is not at all a homework,  but I am interested to find such examples.
 For 1) 
I have R with usual metric and infinite metric space.

For 2) I have set of rational numbers with usual metric.

For 3) 4) 5), I am not sure about my answers.

I know Q, (0,1) are incomplete metric spaces.

I need some basic examples so that I can understand easily.
 Also don't have enough examples of connected metric space.

Comment: $(0,1)$ with the usual metric is not complete. The Cantor set is compact; so is $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. These take care of two of your missing examples, and you already have an example that works for the last one; you just have to recognize it.

Comment: Is (0,1) not complete but connected? Cantor set is compact but not connected?

Comment: Yes to both. You should try to find a Cauchy sequence in$(0,1)$ that doesn't converge to any point of $(0,1)$; it's not hard to do.

Comment: What about 5)? Sorry I am not getting it. And was I correct about 3),4),5)?

Comment: *Not disconnected* is the same as connected; which of the spaces that you've already named is complete and connected? I already agreed with the answers that you suggested for (3) and (4) in your first comment.

Comment: Is R is complete and connected? for the 5)? Because R is the complete that I named and I have (0,1) as connected.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb R$ is connected. The connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are: $\Bbb R$; all sets of the form $[a,b]$ with $a\le b$; all sets of the forms $(a,b),(a,b]$, and $[a,b)$ with $a<b$; all open rays; and all closed rays.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got all the examples.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll stick to examples within the real numbers)

Complete but not compact: the reals work, and are a fine example. Or otherwise $[1,\infty)$, e.g., or that set union some compact set, etc.

Not complete, disconnected: the rationals (usual metric) are fine. Or the irrationals, in the usual metric. Or $(0,1) \cup \{2\}$ will work as well.

Connected, not complete: Indeed $(0,1)$ is an example of this.

Compact but not connected: $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is a simple example, the Cantor set (if you know it) is a more complex one (which is totally disconnected, i.e. has no connected subsets except the singletons),

Complete, not disconnected = Complete and connected: the reals themselves, or $[0,1]$, or $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Is there a complete not connected metric space?

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj yes, the discrete space is the simplest example.